# Partition a set of n integers into m subsets in a way that the maximum subset sum is minimized

Tags: algorithms, sets, partitions, backtracking

Let's say we have a set of `n` integers. I'm trying to find a way to partition this set into `m` subsets (empty subsets are not allowed), so that the maximum subset-sum gets minimized. for example, let's say we have the following set and `m = 2`:

`{11, 5, 11, 5, 10}`

the optimal partitioning will be as follows:

`{5, 5, 11}, {10, 11}`

where the maximum of subset-sums is 21 (no other partition reaches a smaller maximum subset-sum).

The brute force approach will generate all such partitions and find the minimum max sum among them. But is there a better approach to solve this? I was thinking of a backtracking algorithm but I have no idea where to start. I'm only interested in the minimum maximum sum among all partitions and not the partition itself.

Comment: Do you have any additional constraints? If $m$ is very small and your weights are small integers, then you can solve this by generalizing a standard dynamic programming approach for subset-sum (with running time something like $O(num\_items \cdot max\_weight^{m-1})$).

Comment: m, n will not be bigger than say 20. Integers are all positive and less than 125000. Can you elaborate on your solution, please? @Dmitry

Comment: You can generalize https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution. But, given your numbers, the runtime I outlined above is pretty hopeless.

Comment: I think there is hope for a brute-force approach with the following optimization: 1) you guess the answer $a$, and check whether you can get the maximum less than the answer $a$. 2) You process $a$ in decreasing order. There is a chance that the only $a$'s which will take a while are the ones close to the correct answer. With a bunch of other optimizations, it may work out somehow.

Comment: BTW, your problem is equivalent to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical-machines_scheduling. You can check what the literature says about solving it. Probably, your best practical approach would be to use an Integer Linear Programming solver.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be shown to be weakly NP-hard by noticing that it is a generalization of *partition*. In particular, when $m=2$ the input set of integers is a yes instance of *partition* if and only if the measure of an optimal solution of your problem equals half the sum of the integers.

The problem can also be shown to be strongly NP-hard by noticing that it is a generalization of *3-partition* in the special case in which all the integers in the input set $S$ are positive and strictly between $\frac{1}{4}\sum_{s \in S} s$ and $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{s \in S} s$. In particular, we can assume that $|S|$  is a multiple of $3$. When $m=|S|/3$ the optimal solution to your problem has measure $\frac{3}{|S|}\sum_{s \in S} s$ if and only if the *3-partition* instance is a yes instance.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But is there a better approach than brute force? I mean can this problem be solved in fewer steps compared to an exhaustive search?

Comment: It's quite similar to bin packing. Bin packing can use some tricks for handling very small and very large item, and they can be adapted.